# Weak form of vector poisson equation

Tags: tensors, vector-fields, poissons-equation

I formulated a physical problem into a vector poisson equation like 
$$ -\nabla^2\vec{A} = \vec{J}$$
and now want to derive the weak form of it. My first approach was to rewrite the Laplacian operator just like I would for scalar fields, as i think all those operations are also valid for vector fields (partially resulting in tensor fields): 
$$-\nabla\cdot\left(\nabla \vec{A} \right)=J$$
First question: Is this a valid formulation?

The normal way forward is to multiply with test function vector field $\vec{v}$ and integrate it over the domain:

$$\int_\Omega -\nabla\cdot\left(\nabla \vec{A} \right)\cdot \vec{v} \:d \Omega=\int_\Omega J\cdot \vec{v} \:d \Omega$$

But than I struggle with the integration by parts formulation including tensor fields. I came up with 
$$\nabla \cdot \left(\nabla\vec{A}\cdot\vec{v}\right) = \left(\nabla\cdot\left(\nabla \vec{A} \right)\right)\cdot\vec{v} \:+ \left(\nabla \vec{A} \right)\cdot\left(\nabla\cdot\vec{v}\right)$$
Is the left hand side of this term valid, a mjultiplication of tensorfield and vector field? Also on the last term in the equation, there is a multiplication of tensorfield and a scalar field, is that valid?

And if they are valid, how would I go on to the weak form with the substituted result?

$$\int_\Omega \nabla \cdot \left(\nabla\vec{A}\cdot\vec{v}\right) \:d \Omega -
 \int_\Omega \left(\nabla \vec{A} \right)\cdot\left(\nabla\cdot\vec{v}\right) \:d \Omega=\int_\Omega J\cdot \vec{v} \:d \Omega$$

I can't imagine how to apply the divergence theorem on this function, which normally is the next step.